# Finding static block name

Tags: static-block, theme-fallback

I am working on theme, but installed sample data as i didn't have data to work on. Now that i am using my own package and theme, the previous default theme left a broken series of images which were slideshow. Either i can make the slideshow work again or remove it, in both cases i don't know where to look for, i have my template path tags enabled, but on those slideshow images there isn't any.

Comment: slider show only home page or all inner page also?

Comment: Go admin side CMS -> Pages and find home in grid and edit this page, After check  editable page in "Content" section any slider show images available or static block called if there then remove or comment after check fronted

Comment: Also Go admin side CMS -> Static Blocks and find any slider show block available or not if available then it is disable and after check fronted..